# favourite/most used folder launcher for xp?

Tags: windows-xp, path, clipboard, favorites, launcher

I am regularly driven round the bend keeping track of folders (file system)

Either I have to have a ton of windows open, each with a different location, or I have to renavigate each and every time using the common dialog 'file open'

Is there an app which can run as a widget or systray app that can remember a magic combo of 'most used/most recent' folder so I can get straight there, also to have an option to put the path into the clipboard would be great.

Anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are plenty ways to skin this cat.

My tool of choice is **[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)** - simply hit **CTRL + D** to add a location to the "Directory Hotlist"

If you fancy something more 'graphical', have a look at **[Standalone Stack](http://www.chrisnsoft.com/standalonestack/)**

[image]

There is also **[Anvir Task Manager Free](http://www.anvir.com/download.htm)**, which automatically populates a list (accessible from tray icon) showing the most recently opened folders (folders can be added manually to this list).

[image]

Comment: Standalone stack looks nice, but it doesn't work as I would expect it to. I'm trying Anvir, just trying to figure out if there is a hotkey to pop up the menus shown above (rather than the anvir task manager UI)

Comment: I like anvir! After using it for a while I can confirm it is def a good little app

Answer (score 2):

What you need is an open/save dialog box extender. Two good and free extenders are listed below:

The open-source [DM2](http://dm2.sourceforge.net/overview.html):

> DM2 inserts an extra button in all
>   default Windows Open/Save dialogs.
>   When clicked, this button shows a pop
>   up menu with user-defined favorite
>   folders and files. Additionally, menu
>   contains a special submenu ('Recent')
>   with latest of previously used files
>   and folders. By selecting one of the
>   available menu items, user may
>   navigate very fast and easily between
>   favorite folders. This significantly
>   saves time while opening and saving
>   files, since it frees user from boring
>   and time wasting browsing!

[image: image2]

[FileBox eXtender](http://www.hyperionics.com/)

[image: image1]

> The button with a little heart on it
>   like this:  displays a "Favorites"
>   menu. The FileBox Extender
>   Configuration window allows you to add
>   your favorite folders, files, document
>   names, or other text items on it. You
>   can use this to make Windows work as
>   you want it to work (not how it wants
>   to do things "out of the box").

Comment: All it seemed to do is add an icon to the systray. I see nothing in word 2007, vs.net 2005 etc

Comment: and it seriously interfered with right-click functionality across all apps, had to kill it in the end...

Comment: I never used it, but it has a fanatical fellowship. Sorry it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I like using more "minimalistic" approaches; usually trying to work with whatever options the OS (Windows in this case) has got. In this case, I create a windows toolbar:
[image: Creating a new toolbar]

Then make a new folder which will contain all the  shortcuts to my preferred folders. Lastly, I place the toolbar at one side of my screen (say, left side) and configure the toolbar to "autohide", show small icons and show text:

[image: Toolbar configuration]

This way I only have to drag a folder's shortcut to the folder representing this toolbar  if I need quick access to it (after opening the toolbar folder by clicking the "open folder" option shown in the previous image).

Finally, I additionally created a small VBS script that allows me to create a new note in the same folder/toolbar. The script is placed at the top of the toolbar:

[image]

And allows me to create a simple text file after entering a title (which is used as the name of the file). The script source is (consider it in the Public Domain):

```
x = InputBox ("Write the title of the new note","Note Title")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
if x <> "" then
    y = "C:\Documents and Settings\myname\My Documents\Notes\"&x&".txt"
    Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set WriteStuff = myFSO.OpenTextFile(y, 8, True)
    WriteStuff.WriteLine(x)
    WriteStuff.WriteLine("")
    WriteStuff.Close
end if
```